# Confusion on Mersenne Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

One fundamental theorem on Mersenne Numbers states: If $q$ is a prime of the form $8k+7, q|M_{(q-1)/2}=2^{(q-1)/2}-1$.

Let $q=7+768z$, So $2^{(q-1)/2}-1=2^{384z+3}-1=2^{3(128z+1)}-1=(2^{(128z+1)}-1)(2^{2(128z+1)}+2^{(128z+1)}+1)$,

$q|(2^{(128z+1)}-1)(2^{2(128z+1)}+2^{(128z+1)}+1)$,

My confusion starts here;

if $q|(2^{(128z+1)}-1)$,and $128z+1 $ is prime implies that  $(2^{(128z+1)}-1)$ is always composite and $7+768z$ is one of its prime divisors.
Please tell me what I am missing...

Comment: More generally, a prime $q$ is of the form $8k\pm 1$ iff $q\mid M_{(q-1)/2}=2^{(q-1)/2}-1$. It is a consequence of [Euler's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [Quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt to clarify the question.

$q=7+z768$,
if $q|(2^{(128z+1)}-1)$,$128z+1 $ is prime, implies that  $(2^{(128z+1)}-1)$ is always composite and $7+768z$ is one of its prime divisors. This can not be true since there are mersenne primes with exponents of the form $128z+1$.

So either $q|(2^{2(128z+1)}+2^{(128z+1)}+1)$ or $q|(2^{(128z+1)}-1)$. Is there a way to know which case is true?